# Realm Append managed object to unmanaged object

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I want to append managed object to unmanaged object in realm.

Here is the codes

```
class Schedule3: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @objc dynamic var _id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var _partition: String = ""
    let scheduleTags = RealmSwift.List<ScheduleTag3>()
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}

class ScheduleTag3: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @objc dynamic var _id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var _partition: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}
```

When I add managed `ScheduleTag3` object to unmanaged `Schedule3` object and append  `@ObsevedResults(Schedule3.self)`, I get error `'Object is already managed by another Realm. Use create instead to copy it into this Realm.'`
Here is the code of append,

```
struct SchedulePreview: View {
    @ObservedResults(Schedule3.self) var schedules
    @ObservedResults(ScheduleTag3.self) var tags
    @EnvironmentObject var scheduleModel:ScheduleIDModel
    var scheduleTitle:String
    var scheduleBudget:Int
    var areaTag:ScheduleTag3?
    @StateRealmObject var thisSchedule = Schedule3()
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: self.$selection) {
            ...
            .navigationBarItems (
                trailing: Text("make")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        thisSchedule = scheduleModel.addSchedule(scheduleTitle: scheduleTitle, scheduleBudget: scheduleBudget, areaTag: areaTag)
                        let scheduleId = thisSchedule._id
                        let areTagId = areaTag?._id
                        let thisAreaTag = tags.filter("_id == %@", areTagId!).first
                        thisSchedule.scheduleTags.append(thisAreaTag!)
                        $schedules.append(thisSchedule)
                    }
            )

      }
    }
    class ScheduleIDModel: ObservableObject {
    ...

    func addSchedule(scheduleTitle:String, scheduleBudget:Int, areaTag:ScheduleTag3?) -> Schedule3 {
        let schedule = Schedule3()
        if scheduleTitle != "" {
            schedule.title = scheduleTitle
        }
        schedule.budget = scheduleBudget
        schedule._partition = "Public"
        return schedule
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you need more information, please ask me!

Comment: This question is not clear and we don't know which line is throwing the error. Please add a breakpoint to your code and step through it line by line, inspecting the vars and code flow along the way. When it crashes, please update your question with which line is crashing. It's also not clear why `thisSchedule` is instantiated in the struct `@StateRealmObject var thisSchedule = Schedule3()` and then another is instantiated in the `addSchedule` function `let schedule = Schedule3()`